# How to pull only the value from lscpu in Linux?

Tags: regex, linux

If i want to get the CPU Mhz I use.

```
lscpu | grep "CPU MHz"
# CPU MHz:               1200.031
```

I only want to keep the 1200.031, how would I filter the CPU MHz: in the terminal?

Comment: use sed/awk or whatever at the cli.

Comment: Try `sed -n 's/cpu MHz[\t]*: //p' /proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the leading whitespace leaving only the MHz value, you can do:

```
lscpu | sed -n 's/CPU MHz:[ \t]*//p'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use cut.

```
    lscpu | grep "CPU MHz" | cut -d":" -f 2
```